# 403 On WordPress install directory running from a windows laptop running nGinx

Tags: wordpress, windows, nginx, php-8.2

I am running nGinx on a windows laptop and I am trying to install wordpress to html fodler. When index.html works. However, when trying to get to wordpress folder in the same directory and install it shows a 403 forbiden resource.
PHP 8.2 is installed to windows as well.

Can someone suggest some solution?

Best regards

I tried editing properties, but it didn¨t work.
First, readonly, is always enabled and can not be disabled.
Second, I have opened up all permisions on for all users and it didn¨t work either.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).